# Selective compiling in CMake by passing command line arguments

Tags: makefile, cmake

I have three programs, for example: `program_1.cpp`, `program_2.cpp` and `program_3.cpp`.

As of now, I have separate makefiles to build these programs.

I would like to implement in this in the below manner.

```sh
cmake "program_1"   # program_1.cpp has to compile
cmake "program_2"   # program_2.cpp has to compile
cmake "program_3"   # program_3.cpp has to compile
```

Could you suggest me the ways to achieve this?

---

[**UPDATE**]:

I am using a shell script in order to compile the program.
For example

```sh
bash build_script.sh build
```

This would compile the file `program_1.cpp` and generates the executables.

In the same manner, I would like to implement the below approach.

```sh
bash build_script.sh build program_1 -- build program_1.cpp
bash build_script.sh build program_2 -- build program_2.cpp
bash build_script.sh build program_3 -- build program_3.cpp
```

Comment: Just to be clear: do you want to have cmake conditionally only generate makefiles for one program, or do you want to be able to compile only one program at a time from the makefiles generated by cmake?

Comment: Both the approaches should be fine assuming that only one program runs at a time when I give cmake "program_1"....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When generating makefiles, cmake creates a make target for each `add_executable()` call, so it's only  matter of using `make target` on the makefiles that are generated by cmake:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
...
add_executable(program_1 prog1.cpp)
add_executable(program_2 prog2.cpp)
add_executable(program_3 prog3.cpp)
```

And then when comes time to build:

```
cmake path/to/source/dir
make program_1
```

Comment: Thanks for the steps. I got the clear picture how to select particular program while compiling. I will be updating the question. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant three different targets to compile, you can have a simple makefile:

```
.PHONY program_1:
program_1:
    gcc -o program_1 program_1.cpp

.PHONY program_2:
program_2:
    gcc -o program_2 program_2.cpp

.PHONY program_3:
program_3:
    gcc -o program_3 program_3.cpp
```

Then you can simply do:

```
make program_2
```

To compile just program_2. This has nothing to do with cmake however.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Will try the method and let you know.